# L'adjectif « fou » après le nom pour « considérable, exceptionnel » : syntagmes figés ?

Tags: adjectifs, registre

Je lis qu'on peut employer l'adjectif [*fou/folle*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/fou_ou_fol) après un nom pour signifier « considérable, exceptionnel » (*succès fou*, *vitesse folle*)(Usito). S'agit-il de syntagmes plutôt figés ? Puis-je parler :

> ...d'habiletés de chasse folles...

...d'un oiseau par exemple ? Est-ce d'un registre courant ?

Answer (score 1):

On doit pouvoir utiliser ***fou*** comme tu le décris avec la plupart des mots qui correspondent à quelque chose auxquelles on peut attribuer une intensité : *Cet oiseau a **un talent fou** pour la chasse,* si j'ai bien compris ce que signifie *habilité de chasse*.

Beaucoup de bien : un bien fou
Enormément de mal : un mal fou
Beaucoup de monde : un monde fou
Beaucoup de temps : un temps fou
Une prix très élevé : un prix fou
Une vitesse exagérée : une vitesse folle
Une rage extrême : une rage folle
Une envie irrépressible : une envie folle
...
mais :
Un homme très grand : <s>Une homme fou</s> ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fou)) **I**
> F.− [Fou sert à indiquer une grande quantité ou le haut degré] (Quasi-)synon. considérable, extraordinaire.
>
> 1. **[En position d'épithète postnominal d'un subst. précédé d'un art. indéf.]**
>    • Avoir un travail, un succès fou; gagner un argent fou; des prix fous; une vitesse folle.
>    • Il (...) lance, du bout de son pied, un ballon à des hauteurs folles (Gyp, Souv. pte fille,1927, p. 64).
>    • Il dit (...) que c'est d'une gravité folle... qu'il faut prendre des mesures, toute affaire cessante... qu'il faut peut-être envisager d'urgence le déplacement de son quartier général (Romains, Verdun,1938, p. 193).Ils sont couchés depuis longtemps (...).
>    • « Depuis un temps fou, depuis des heures » (Butor, Passage Milan,1954, p. 223)
>    • ... il fait soleil. Il fait même un soleil fou. Il vient de tous les coins du ciel à la fois à travers les déchirures des nuées. Il balaie tout le paysage comme un faisceau de phare, comme un phare tournant à cent faisceaux. Giono, Noé,1947, p. 58.
> 2. a) **C'est fou + prop. exclam.**
>    • C'est fou ce que nous avons pu boire, Modigliani et moi, et quand j'y pense, j'en suis épouvanté (Cendrars, Bourlinguer,1948, p. 199).
>    • « C'est fou comme vous pouvez prendre les choses au sérieux! On dirait que vous jouez votre tête! » (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954, p. 521).
>    b) **C'est fou + subst. suivi d'une relative.**
>    • C'est fou tout le bien qu'ils pensent de vous (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954p. 324).
>    • Tout le monde disait du bien de son livre, c'était fou le courrier qu'il avait reçu (Beauvoir, Mandarins,1954p. 99).
>
> **Rem.** Lorsque le subst. est au plur. ou est un subst. collectif, la constr. ci-dessus implique une idée de grande quantité.

D'après le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de), il existe une relation représentée par « de » qui correspond aux termes (« habileté » , « chasse »).

> **B.− De marque la condition préalable d'un procès ou du résultat d'un procès matériel ou moral.**
> **2. [Dans un compl. déterminatif (genre, espèce)]**
> **b) [En parlant d'inanimés abstr.]**
> • Toutes les fois que la personnalité est opprimée, que la liberté individuelle n'a pas son équitable manifestation, il y a **crime de lèse-humanité** (Du Camp, Hollande,1859, p. 248)
> • Le roman, entend-on couramment répéter, se sépare actuellement en deux genres bien distincts : le roman psychologique et le **roman de situation**. D'un côté, ceux de Dostoïevski, de l'autre, ceux de Kafka. Sarraute, L'Ère du soupçon,1956, p. 9.

Le préliminaire que fournit le cadre d'utilisation dans l'entrée du TLFi pour « de » ne permet cependant pas de décider finalement de la validité de cet assemblage. Prenons par exemple la construction « finesses de vie », qui semble être une expression normale selon le modèle qui vient d'être exposé, et on sent que quelque chose manque, quelque chose d'indéfinissable qui explique quand même que cette expression n'est pas définie ; en d'autre mots elle ne correspond à rien que l'on puisse identifier de près ou de loin. Un peu la même chose est ressentie pour « habileté de chasse », cependant à un degré bien moindre.

Seulement en fréquence appréciable depuis les années 90 du siècle dernier on trouve des termes comme les suivants ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22habilet%C3%A9s%20de%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) :

- habiletés de (dévoilement, communication, régulation de la colère, compréhension de concepts verbaux, décodage, pensée dans une intervention, « parler » et d'« écrire », représentation symbolique, vie autonome, réflexion, résolution de problème, raisonnement, traduction, direction, vie communautaire, main, etc.).

L'usage assez récemment introduit expliquerait, tout au moins en partie, la nature quelque peu étrange de cette construction ; néanmoins, l'ampleur de sa fréquence  depuis la fin du siècle dernier oblige que l'on doive le considérer comme idiomatique.

Modifier ce groupe nominal par « folles » est possible, à mon avis (« des habiletés de chasse folles »), mais selon la remarque dans la définition de cet adjectif, cela ne signifie pas nécessairement « des habiletés de chasse considérables » mais pourrait vouloir dire« des habiletés de chasses innombrables ».

*grande quantité*

- un monde fou, (« foule folle » signifie toujours « foule remplie de folie », ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22foule%20folle%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), pléonasme),

L'usage est assez capricieux. Par exemple, on ne dira pas « Il a une famille folle. » pour dire il a beaucoup de famille, mais « C'est fou ce qu'il a de famille ! ». On ne dira pas non plus « Des herbes folles couvraient les abords. » pour dire qu'il y avait beaucoup d'herbe, la raison de cela étant que « [herbe folle](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fou) » est un idiotisme où « fou » n'a plus le même sens.

*On trouve les combinaisons suivantes*

- orage fou, pluie folle, vent fou,

*On ne trouve pas*

- des inondations folles, un mauvais temps fou, une avalanche folle,

C'est un usage qui peut tendre vers l'ambigüité.

• ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Champs_du_signe/J1crAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22vent+fou%22&dq=%22vent+fou%22&printsec=frontcover)) et un vent fou , se démenant au - dessus des plaines ...

- Des flammes folles dans la cheminée montaient presque jusqu'au manteau. (user LPH)  (*S'agit-il de « flammes considérables » ou de la définition «  [Qui va en tout sens en donnant l'apparence du désordre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fou) » ?*)

Après les indications qui ont précédé et qui sont une tentative de cerner l'usage, on peut dire finalement que dans la langue parlée des cas comme les suivants sont courants alors que d'autres ne se trouvent pas. Il y a donc une question de collocation qui entraine plus ou moins des restrictions sur l'usage.

- un monde fou, un prix fou, un temps fou, un mal de tête fou, une migraine folle, un mal fou à (faire quelque chose), un travail fou, un talent fou, des distances folles, des hauteurs folles, un amour fou, une affection folle, un entrain fou, à un train fou, une chaleur folle, des exagérations folles,  …
- <s>grippe folle, mal de dent fou, un rhume fou, une surprise folle, une aptitude folle, un froid fou …</s>